# alter table xyz drop column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table with 200 column, I have to drop 96 columns from this table.

Using the statement

```
alter table XYZ drop column a,b,c,d...................
```

is taking forever to drop the column on SQL Server2000

Can anyone help or give me some idea how can this be done effitiently..

thanks

Comment: Why not manually delete them in design view in ssms or query analyser?

Comment: My first thought would be to make sure you don't have any foreign keys tied to those columns or any cascading changes that would occur as a result.  I'm not familiar enough with MSSQL 2000, but I would hope it wouldn't let you drop a column that was (or part of) a primary key, since doing so could introduce duplicate keys.

Comment: There is no primary key associated with those columns.

Comment: In ssms, it freezes out :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a trivial change to ask of any RDBMS and IS likely to take a while. Depending on the platform, it might also be exacerbated if there are a lot of rows and the columns you're dropping contain non-null data.

Perhaps it would be more feasible to SELECT the columns you want to keep into a new table, drop this one, and rename the new table to the original table name.

*Answer intentionally written generically*